# Expires setting in mongoose schema is ignored if index already exists at MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-indexes

I'm using the `expires` field in a [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) schema in order to set expiration on a given field. For instance:

```
var Crumbs = new Schema({
    ...
    timestamp: {
      type: Date,
      expires: 3600,
      required: true
    },
    ...
});
```

The effect is the expected one and the following index is created at MongoDB *if the index doesn't previously exist*:

```
> db.crumbs.getIndexes()
[
    ...
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "timestamp" : 1
        },
        "name" : "timestamp_1",
        "ns" : "mydb.crumbs",
        "expireAfterSeconds" : 36000,
        "background" : true
    }
]
```

However, if the index previously exists it is not created. For instance, if I change to `expires: 360` in my code and I re-run my program, `"expireAfterSeconds"` at MongoDB keeps being `36000`.

Is there any way to force the index to use the value defined in the schema, even if the index already exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Alex Blex hint, I have finally solved this. First droping the index, then recreating with the new expiration value:

```
mongoose.connections[0].collections.crumbs.dropIndex({timestamp: 1}, function (error) {
    if (error) {
        // This happens typically if the index doesn't exist but it doesn't hurt anyway
    }
    mongoose.connections[0].collections.crumbs.ensureIndex({timestamp: 1}, {expireAfterSeconds: 360});
});
```

Comment: There is no need to create index manually. Mongoose should create one from the schema, if it doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it from schema definition.

The best way is to drop index directly in the db.

Alternatively, drop it from the script. E.g.

```
mongoose.connections[0].collections("collectionname")
.dropIndex("propertyName",callback)
```

Comment: Thanks! You hint has been very useful (see my self-anwser)